# AddWithValue-Statement in ASP.NET doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to get a specific value out of my Database.
To do so I wrote a function that I call like that:

```
strUserId = SqlSelectToString("SELECT UserId FROM BugNet.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @UserName");
```

The function works like that:

```
private string SqlSelectToString(string strSqlCommand)
{
    string result = "";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSqlCommand, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", strUserName);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                result = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
```

I tried many different approaches but wasn't able to add "strUserName" to the query.

The query-string remained always "SELECT UserId FROM BugNet.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @UserName".

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The Username of whom we need the UserId is always the same and defined by the Webserver-Admin through the Web.config as follows:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="UserName" value="kunde"/>
<add key="ApplicationName" value="InternalTest"/>
```

before the method SqlSelectToString is executed I fetch the strUsername from the config like that:

```
strUserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString();
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

Finally found a solution to the problem.
This is the right approach:

```
private const string strSelectUserId = "SELECT UserId FROM BugNet.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @UserName";

/// <summary>
/// Saves the result of an SQL-Query in a string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strSqlCommand"></param>
private string SqlSelectToString(string strSqlCommand)
{
    string result = "";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSqlCommand, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", strUserName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationName", strApplicationName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", strProjectId);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result = reader[0].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        bInsert = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It,s the correct query-string. Your query will be passed to the SQL server with extra data contains your parameters. The actual string in .net app will not changed.

Comment: Where have you seen such a query string? Was it in SQL Profiler or in your .NET code under debugger? If second one - this is normal behavior, if first one - this is impossible using code you've shown. So what is your actual problem?

Comment: I saw in my Debugger, that the command Text won't change. So you think this should work as intended?

Comment: here is the million dollar question, where are you getting and or assigning `strUserName` have you even used the debugger to step through the code.. also there is no need for the `connection.Close()` explicit call the using statement handles the auto disposing of the connection object also you should change the method signature to return a datatable are you familiar with the fill method..? I will post a method that you can you and it will parse the parameters it's fairly straight forward and easy to follow

Comment: I know about the Connection.Close, but forgot to delete it. strUserName is a private string that is globally declared in the aspx.cs-file we are in and has a specific value at the time the function gets called. @MethodMan

Comment: you are wanting to return the data you need to return it in a DataTable you are going about this the wrong way you can even use a DataAdapter to utilize the fill command to return the data as well also are you sure that there will always be `1` record in the database for the username? if not then ExecuteScalar() is not the correct method. I will post a simple example on how you can do this

Comment: strUserName is defined through the web.config. The function is supposed to save the User ID which belongs to the Username in a string. It's as simple as that. @MethodMan

Comment: strUserName defined in the web.config..? please show and post all relevant code.. is the user always the same username? I have posted something that should give you more than enough to get you started.. also what do you mean that the function is supposed to save the `UserId` you have not shown any code that references the `web.config` file etc.. can you edit your original question and show also what the web.config looks like

Comment: you should also have the connection string setup in the web.config so that way you won't have to fully qualify the Table using the `.dbo` you really should just be using `Select UserId from Users Where...etc` once again can you please show the connection string.. also please share with us any errors that you may be getting as well

Comment: `<add key="UserName" value="kunde"/>` are you the only user that will be accessing the database..? if so this is sill not a good approach anyway.. where is the code that shows how you are getting the username from the .config file..? your app does not automatically know this.. you need to access it by using something like this 
`var  userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];`

Answer (score 1):

> The query-string remained always "SELECT UserId FROM BugNet.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @UserName".

This is what is **supposed** to happen. It's the *whole point* of parameterized queries. The parameter value is *never* substituted directly into the sql command, and thus any possibility of an [sql injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is avoided. Instead, it's more as if you executed sql code like this:

```
declare @UserName nvarchar(50);
set @UserName =  '... magic here to populate this without actually building sql code';

SELECT UserId FROM BugNet.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @UserName
```

<sup>*(Though for Sql Server it actually relies on [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx))*</sup>

I'd help you more, but you never tell us what actually happens after you run the code... and this is likely because you **swallow any exception that might tell you what went wrong**. The code you have is almost certainly throwing an exception that would tell you exactly what's going wrong here, and you never get to see it.

Seriously, just remove the try/catch from that code entirely. You don't need it at all, and the entire catch block is just extra code.

One more thing before I go: [AddWithValue() isn't the best option for your query parameters.](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Put all that together, you end up with a helper method that looks more like this:

```
private string GetSqlScalar(string strSqlCommand, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    string result = "";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSqlCommand, connection))
    {
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        }

        connection.Open();
        result = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
strUserId = GetSqlScalar("SELECT UserId FROM BugNet.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @UserName", 
    new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50) {Value = strUserNanme });
```

<sup>(Of course using the correct parameter type and length from the database).</sup>